# Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. And define equality ($x=z$) iff $x=(0,x)$. Is this equality well defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, definition, equivalence-relations

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$. And define equality ($x=z$) iff $x=(0,x)$. Is this equality well defined ?

Okay. It is easily shown that something goes wrong if you define equality in this way.

$$1=1\cdot 1=(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=i^2=-1$$

But how do I call this what goes wrong here? In some sense I would think that my definition is a well defined equivalence relation. But I'm certainly doing something wrong here.

I would like to understand this better then just finding with counterexamples that I can't define something this way. I would like to understand the "root" of my wrong definition.

Note: I know that the usual definition is that $x=(x,0)$, I'm just playing around. I think my head has a hard time understanding the logic behind the equality $x=(x,0)$. My head says something, can't I define such a equality just like that. What do I need to show to say that this equality is well defined ?

Answer (score 2):

You assume that $\,x \equiv ix\,$ for all $\,x\in\Bbb R.\,$ As you show, this implies $\,1 \equiv -1,\,$ so $\,2 \equiv 0,\,$ so $\,1 \equiv 0,\,$ so the quotient ring generated by this congruence relation is the trivial one-element ring (or, you have reached a contradiction if you are working only with fields, where $\,1\ne 0\,$ by hypothesis).

Comment: I don't assume that $x= ix$. I assume that $x= (0,x)$ but I don't assume that $x= (x,0)$. So I can't say that $(0,x)= ix$, as this would follow from $x=(x,0)$. Note that $(0,x)=(0,1)(x,0)=i(x,0)=ix$.

Comment: @kasper What is the multiplication you are using, i.e. what is the value of $(a,b)(c,d)$? Maybe you intend to ask about the natural injection of $\,\Bbb R\,$ in $\,\Bbb C\,$ instead of what you wrote above. If so you have some tuples swapped.

Comment: $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$

Comment: Ok, so, as usual, $\,(a,b)\,$ denotes $\,a+bi.\,$ So when you construct an equivalence relation equating $\,x\in R\,$ with $\,(0,x) = xi$ you get $\,x\equiv xi.\,$ Probably you meant instead to use $\,(x,0),\,$ i.e. $\, x+0i,\,$ assuming you intend to study the natural injection of $\,\Bbb R\,$ into $\,\Bbb C.$

Comment: Where can I read more about the natural injection of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ you are talking about ? From three different books that I've read, they don't say that $(a,b)$ means $a+bi$. They say deduce it like:
$$(x,y)=(x,0)+(0,y)=(x,0)+(y,0)(0,1)=x+iy$$

If you have that $x=(x,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$.

Comment: Right, and $\,(x,0)+(x',0) = (x+x',0)\,$ and $\,(x,0)(x',0) = (xx',0)$ so the complex numbers of the form $\,(x,0)\,$ form a subring isomorphic to $\,\Bbb R.\,$ But in your question you used  $\,(0,x),\,$ when you probably meant $\,(x,0).\ \ $

Comment: Pleas read my question carefully. In the last paragraph I clearly explain why I use $(0,x)$ instead of $(x,0)$. I understand the set forms a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but does this justify writing $x=(x,0)$ ?

Comment: @Kasper Are you perchance reading a discussion where with set-surgery they "splice" a copy of the set $\,\Bbb R\,$ into $\,\Bbb R^2,\,$ i.e. replace each *tuple* $\,(x,0)\in\Bbb R^2\,$ by the real number $\,x\in\Bbb R\,$ to get $\, \Bbb R \subset \Bbb C\,?$ (vs. $\,\Bbb R\,$ is *isomorphic* to a subring of $\,\Bbb C).\ \ $

Comment: I'm not reading such a discussion, are you ? (Not sure how I should interpret your question )

Comment: @Kasper Then why do you think that there is an *equality* $\,x = (x,0)\,$ when showing that the subring $(\Bbb R,0)$ is isomorphic to $\,\Bbb R\,?$ There is no such equality of elements because the real number $\,x\,$ is not an element of the set $\,\Bbb R^2.\,$ Instead one proves that the map $\,h(x) = (x,0)\,$ is a ring isomorphism of $\,\Bbb R\,$ with the subring $\,(\Bbb R,0)\subset \Bbb R^2 \cong \Bbb C,\,$ i.e. $\,h(x+y) = h(x)+h(y),\,$ and $\,h(xy) = h(x)h(y).\ \ $

Comment: Well, I've read three books about complex analysis (just the beginning). And in these books, they prove $\,(x,0)+(x',0) = (x+x',0)\,$ and $\,(x,0)(x',0) = (xx',0)$. After they proved that, they begin to write $x=(x,0)$. Therefore I think somehow this isomorphism must prove the equality $x=(x,0)$.

Comment: For example in Rudin, they use it: http://snag.gy/Zv5kh.jpg

Comment: @Kasper Ah, that explains it! You should have said that in your question. That's simply an abuse of notation. You can think of $\,x\,$ as an abbreviation for $\,(x,0).\,$ It comes from $1 := (1,0),\ i := (0,1)\,$ so $\,a+bi = a(1,0)+b(0,1) = (a,b).\,$ Technically, one could make it be a set=theoretic equality of elements by doing said set-theoretic surgery, but there is no need for that (there might be if one was working in foundation sor writing computer algorithms).

Comment: Sorry, it is sometimes hard to understand what I don't understand ;) So I should interpret it as: Because it is an isomorphism, we have the same rules for arithmetic, and therefore we can abuse notation a little bit ($x=(x,0)$) without worrying about strange equalities like $1=-1$ ?

Comment: @Kasper Yes, you can view it like that. Those strange equalities result because you are essentially trying to prove that $\,(0,\Bbb R) = \Bbb R i\cong \Bbb R\,$ (false), instead of $\,(\Bbb R,0)\cong \Bbb R\  $ (true).

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your "equality" is actually an equivalence relation. So we have x is equivalent to z iff x=(0,x). But in C x=(x,0). Thus, x is equivalent to z iff x=0, and the relation is not reflexive. Okay, so maybe the second equality was also supposed to mean your equivalence relation? Then you are defining your relation in terms of itself. In your example it seems like you are saying (a,o) is equivalent to (o,a) {That is, your equivalence relation is only defined for elements in R and elements in the imaginaries, not their sums). To preserve addition, you must have (a,a) is equivalent to (2a,0) for all a. With a little fiddling, you should have (a,b) is equalivent to (c,d) if (a+b=c+d). This is already going beyond your definition though! This leads to 1=-1. What the moral of the story should be is that equivalence relations do not necassarily preserve a particular operation. You can always extend your equivalence relation to accomodate the operations but then you might get a trivial algebraic structure in the end. You have to pick your equivalence relation carefully (such as in quotienting by an ideal)